# How can i config stub_request to get response code 200

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a request and in the response i use this:

```
def get_request
  ...
  return response.code == "200"
end
```

but when i set in the spec:

```
stub_request(:get, 'https:domain.com/stock').to_return(status: 200)
```

I get this error: `` undefined method `code' for false:FalseClass ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add a body with data like the response in production.

```
stub_request(:get, 'https:domain.com/stock')
  .to_return(status: 200, body: JSON.generate(available: []))
```